# apache commons file upload api not running properly

Tags: jsp, servlets, apache-commons

i have done a file upload webpage using apache commons,what happens here is like sometimes it uploads the file and some time it doesnt upload the file,i dont know where the problem is,whether it is within the code(but it uploads the files) or in the network, because my output page will show"file uploaded successfully" if the file is uploaded in the server,i have tested my code many times and it was working fine for single and multiple uploads.the problem started when the page was hosted from a web server(apache tomcat).

```
import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

public class uploadpagedb extends HttpServlet {  
 private String fileName="";        
 private String main="";  
 private String location;  
 private String sub;  
 private File uploadFile;  
 private String filen;
 private String filetype;
@Override
public void init(){  
}  
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{        
    ResultSet rs=null;
    PreparedStatement psmnt=null;
 try 
  {  
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();          
    DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();          
    ServletFileUpload fileUpload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);         
    List items = fileUpload.parseRequest(request);  
    Iterator ir = items.iterator();  
     while(ir.hasNext()){  
     FileItem item = (FileItem)ir.next();   
String name = item.getFieldName();  
if(item.isFormField())
{  
 if(name != null)  
 {  
 if(name.equals("fileName"))
 {  
  fileName = item.getString();  
 }
 else if(name.equals("main"))
 {  
  main = item.getString();  
 }
 else if(name.equals("sub"))
 {
     sub=item.getString();
 }
 else if(name.equals("filetype"))
 {
     filetype=item.getString();
 }
 }  
}
else
{  
    String file1=item.getFieldName();
    String file2=item.getName();
    filen=file2;
 location = File.separator+"home"+File.separator+"adapco"+File.separator+"Desktop"+ File.separator +"output"+ File.separator +main+File.separator+sub+File.separator+filen;
 uploadFile = new File(location);        
 long size = item.getSize();  
 if(size <= 1024*1024*1024)
 {  
  item.write(uploadFile);  
  //out.println("Your File is uploaded successfully ");  
 }else{  
  out.println("Your File is not uploaded.File size should be less than 1GB");  
 }
 String concat=main+"/"+sub;
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ksa","root","root");
     java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime());
     String status="n";
     int count=0;

     Statement st=con.createStatement();
     rs=st.executeQuery("select count(filename) as filename from file1 where filename='"+filen+"' and category='"+concat+"'");

     while(rs.next())
     {
     //String category1=rs.getString(1);
     count=rs.getInt(1);
     }
     if(count==1)
     {
        int dup=st.executeUpdate("update file1 set filename='"+filen+"' where category='"+concat+"'");
        out.println("file updated successfully");
     }
     else
     {
     psmnt=(PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("insert into file1(filedesc,category,filepath,filename,Date,filetype,status)values(?,?,?,?,'"+sqlDate+"',?,'"+status+"')");
     psmnt.setString(1, fileName);
     psmnt.setString(2, concat);
     psmnt.setString(3, location);
     psmnt.setString(4, filen);
     psmnt.setString(5, filetype);
     int ff=psmnt.executeUpdate();
    // InetAddress ownIP=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
     String ownIP=request.getRemoteAddr();
     psmnt=(PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("insert into updatelog values('"+ownIP+"')");
     int sysip=psmnt.executeUpdate();
     out.println("Your File is uploaded successfully ");  
     }
   }  
  }         
    //out.println("uploaded successfully");        
  //response.sendRedirect("uploadfile.jsp");                          
 } 
 catch (Exception e) 
 {  
  System.out.println("Error"+e.getMessage());
 }  
 }  
 }
```

Comment: @BalusC I am having the same problem. Did you solve this problem? see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36891524/file-upload-not-working-using-servletupload-parserequest-method

Answer (score -1):

You could try using

```
uploadFile = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath(location));
```

This will create the file(with your folder structure) within your web app's root folder.
If the file location is ok, then change the line

```
String file2=item.getName();
```

to

```
String file2 = new File(item.getName()).getName();
```

because the IE browser sends complete path on client's machine.

Comment: ...which would get lost when you redeploy the webapp or in some server configurations even when you just restart the server, with the simple reason that the uploaded file is not part of the original WAR/EAR. You should absolutely not store uploaded files in expanded WAR folder. Also, whether `getRealPath()` returns non-`null` is dependent on the server configuration (sometimes it's not expanded into disk, but instead into memory), you don't want to be dependent on that.

Comment: @BalusC I looked at the source code of the Commons IO method that the Commons FileUpload FAQ suggests. I also looked at the source code of java.io.File method getName. They are basically the same. They both use the String method lastIndexOf(separator) to create a substring. So I don't understand your objection. I use the Streaming API so I don't have the dependency on Commons IO. So that is why I prefer my way.

Comment: @BalusC,iam running the page from linux machine,the file is uploaded in its desired location,but the same page is not working sometimes, to be more specific i have already created the folders for eg: if iam uploading a file in the dir /home/user/Desktop/output/filename.extn,the file will be uploaded successfully in the above defined path,but if i upload another file after a while then the file is not uploading in its location

Comment: @rickz:the page is uploading the files alternatively(working and not working) in the path.

Comment: What happens when it is "not working"? You should add some debug lines. Print out the file2 variable. Also you could show us your complete code. Do you have the above posted code in a try block ? What is in your catch block?

Comment: @rickz P:i have pasted my full code,as i said before the file is uploading alternatively ,one more thing happened is like the file is not getting updated if we try to upload same file

Comment: @BalusC :i have pasted my full code ,as far as i know the page uploads the file but if i try to upload after some times then it is not getting uploaded.

Comment: I am not familiar with database code. So, I can't help you with that. The only problem that I see is with using IE browser as I posted above here.